# program to Send Scheduled Facebook Message

Tags: facebook, messaging

Is there ANY way to write a simple program that can automatically send a pre-specified Facebook message to a certain person repeatedly at a pre-specified time?

Comment: No. And it's not allowed either.

Comment: What do you mean "not allowed"?

Comment: You are not allowed to automate functionality that is intended to be used by real users, such as sending private messages.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/facebook-chat-api

It is an "unofficial API" for FB messenger that uses node.js to emulate the browser in order to send FB messages on a user account. As previously mentioned, this is technically a violation of the FB TOS. Still, it is possible. You could also potentially accomplish this with Selenium...or a really complex Chron job maybe, but this is the preferred way (from what I understand) to do this.